# matplotlib shows my image but cv2.imwrite() just saves blackness

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing, colors

After converting the original *.jpg file, using the "reference white color" method (the idea is from [here](https://jmanansala.medium.com/image-processing-with-python-color-correction-using-white-balancing-6c6c749886de))

```
def whitepatch_balancing(image, from_row, from_column, row_width, column_width):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
    ax[0].imshow(image)
    ax[0].add_patch(Circle((from_column, from_row),
                              linewidth=3,
                              edgecolor='r', facecolor='none'));

    ax[0].set_title('Original image')
    image_patch = image[from_row:from_row+row_width, from_column:from_column+column_width]
    image_max = (image*1.0 / image_patch.max(axis=(0, 1))).clip(0, 1)
    ax[1].imshow(image_max);
    ax[1].set_title('Whitebalanced Image with MAX value of white')
    plt.show()
    return image_max

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = imread('img.jpg')
    balanced_img = whitepatch_balancing(image, 60, 1230, 20, 20)
```

if the original image (in RGB format) looked like this: [[[131 152 205], [120 143 195], ..., [135 150 191]]]

then the resulting array after conversion looks something like this: [[[0.99242424 0.98701299 1. ], [0.90909091 0.92857143 1. ], ..., [0.84090909 0.64285714 0.21025641]]]

using matplotlib.pyplot as plt, you can display the picture and see that the color correction has occurred [original and converted images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0JlM.png)

but if you try to save the converted array to a file *.jpeg or *.png - we get just a black picture (all pixel values are less than one)

how can the resulting result (the converted image) be adequately saved to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your balanced_image has been scaled between 0 and 1, so you will need to rescale it back between 0, 255 before saving it. Your rgb values are <1 for all channels which is basically black.

```
balanced_img = whitepatch_balancing(image, 60, 70, 60, 70)
cv2.imwrite('test.png', balanced_img*255)
```

Comment: balanced_img*255 - will give the wrong result

but the code below will give the correct one:
scaleArr = np.dot(balanced_img, 255)
rounded_scaleArr = np.rint(scaleArr)

Comment: The dot product gives identical results, so you could round the floats before saving if you want, sure.

Comment: I tried multiplying the matrix simply by a scalar (255) and for some reason it gave different results than "np.dot()", but maybe I was wrong. In any case, I am grateful to you for the answer!

Comment: if a simple multiplication failed (it should not), show us how it failed, incluing [mre] -- at most there might be some np.clip() required. you already do that in your code though.